# Remote: Server has disabled port forwarding affecting one user

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm working on a linux server that's got several accounts for specific port forwarding operations, and an account that was working previously has stopped working.

Using some verbosity I found the tunnel was failing because the server has disabled port forwarding - but doing some checking and testing it's only this specific user account that's affected.

I've verified the account is not locked out, it has the correct groups (as compared with similar accounts), nothing showing up under pam_tally2.

Where should I go from here?

Thank you!

Comment: look at their authorized_keys maybe?  Restrictions can be applied there.

Comment: Checked the authorized keys, that was good (there was only one for that specific account). It ended up being an expired account password to check that I found you run "chage -l [username]" - that was annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Found this was caused by an expired account password - very subtle as the account isn't allowed to actually login to the system only create a reverse SSH tunnel.

To check password information I found you can run:

```
chage -l [username]
```